# The argument should be of type: const integer;

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to change indicator version 3 pinescript code to version 4, in these process, i face the error

> Cannot call 'operator *' with 'expr2'=fun_ref[totalScore]. The argument should be of type: const integer;

```
normalizedScore=100*totalScore/ maxScore
```

i can not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It's says it cant multiply `100` to a `totalScore`, where `totalScore` is a function reference.
probably right call would be

```
normalizedScore= 100 * totalScore() / maxScore
```

Also feel free to use v3 to v4 converter. (`Convert to V4` button)